# Create a map dynamically in the mapStore

Tags: java, hazelcast

I'm using MapStore to persist the data into Database.

My application is a multi-tenant application so if new tenant comes in how to create a map at run time in mapstore..

if you see in the below code, currently I have hardcoded for tenant-1.

this is my configuration class

```
@Component
public class CacheConfig {

    @Bean
    public static Config config() {

        System.err.println("config class");
        Config config = new Config();
        config.setInstanceName("hazelcast");
        
        
        MapConfig mapCfg = new MapConfig();
        mapCfg.setName("tenant-1");
        mapCfg.setBackupCount(2);
        mapCfg.setTimeToLiveSeconds(300);

        MapStoreConfig mapStoreCfg = new MapStoreConfig();
        mapStoreCfg.setClassName(PersonMapStore.class.getName()).setEnabled(true);
        mapCfg.setMapStoreConfig(mapStoreCfg);
        config.addMapConfig(mapCfg);

        return config;

    }

}
```

Any suggestions would be very helpful..

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use wildcards in the name. For example, you can set the name of the configuration to `tenant-*` to cover all tenants with the names like `tenant-1`, `tenant-2` ...